# Convert dot List of Type T with String seperated with dot to a tree like structure

Tags: c#

I have a list of type T1, with dot as a delimiter for parent child
with

```
[
{
Id: 1,
Name: "child1"
},
{
Id: 2,
Name: "child1.child2"
},
{
Id: 3,
Name: "child1.child2.child3"
},
{
Id: 4,
Name: "child10"
},
{
Id: 5,
Name: "child10.child11"
},
{
Id: 6,
Name: "childT.Son.Son1"
},
{
Id: 7,
Name: "childOne"
},
]
```

i need to convert it to a Tree like structure with this format

```
public class TreeViewDto
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<TreeViewDto> Children { get; set; }
}
```

above example would look like

```
[
{
Id: 1,
Label: "child1",
Children: [{
        Id: 2,
        Label: "child2"
        Children: [{
                        Id: 3,
                        Label: "child3"
                        }]
        },]},
{
Id: 4,
Label: "child10"
},      
    {
Id: 6,
Label: "childT.Son.Son1"
},
{
Id: 7,
Label: "childOne"
},
{
Id: 4,
Label: "child10",
Children: [{
        Id: 5,
        Label: "child11"}]
  }
]
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have two `child10`s with `Id: 4`?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing it is layer-by-layer:

- Make a flat list of name-to-node mappingss
- For each name that has no dot `'.'` in it, add a first-level node to the result; remove the node from the original list
- For each name with a single dot, look up its parent, and add the node as a child; remove the node from the original list
- Repeat the above step for names with two dots, three dots, four dots, and so on
- Adding nodes as subnodes can be simplified with a helper method that takes an array of strings representing the "path" (you can make this array by calling `Split('.')` on full name).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by first creating a helper method, that can get the child of a node by it's label (i.e.:`GetChildByLabel(TreeViewDto parent, string label)`)
Then you could iterate through your list and add the items to the respective parent nodes. And for this to work you would also need an empty root node to receive all those nodes without parents:

```
var root = new TreeViewDto { Children = new List<TreeViewDto>() };
foreach (var el in list) {
    var path = el.Name.Split('.');
    var parent = root;
    int last = path.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        parent = GetChildByLabel(parent, path[i]);
    }
    parent.Children.Add(new TreeViewDto {
        Label = path[last], Id = el.Id, Children = new List<TreeViewDto>()
    });
}
```

Now `root.Children` is the list you wanted.
This will however not work if a child has no parent or if it is listed first.
For the latter case you could first order the list by the number of dots in their names:

```
list.Sort((el1, el2) => el1.Name.Count(c => c == '.') - el2.Name.Count(c => c == '.'));
```

This way the parent node will always appear first in the list.